# how to hide specific model from model lists, not the model-example

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I need to hide a specific model from the model list who is shown on the bottom of the document, but keep it on the model-example.
Just hide specific model, not all of them. I don't want to use `defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1`

Comment: Do you use a standalone Swagger UI (e.g. official npm modules or `dist` assets from its GitHub repo) or is it bundled with some framework/library (e.g. Swashbuckle, Springfox, Springdoc or similar)?

Comment: @Helen I'm using NestJS